# Working outside of request context. Flask, SqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask and SqlAlchemy, the case is that I have a main database and then I have several databases where I get other information. But the credentials are not defined as fixed, so I have to obtain them from a table in the main database, depending on the plant where the user is. For this I use SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. the problem is that when I try to pass the connection string to the Bind I told myself that the function that returns it is out of context. Here a portion of the code

```
def scadaConnect():
    idplanta_session=str(session['idPlanta'])
    usernamequery = db.session.query(Scada.usernameScada).filter(Scada.idPlanta=='5')
    hostquery = db.session.query(Scada.hostScada).filter(Scada.idPlanta=='5')
    passwordquery = db.session.query(Scada.passScada).filter(Scada.idPlanta=='5')
    nombredbquery = db.session.query(Scada.nombrebdScada).filter(Scada.idPlanta=='5')
    nombredb = str(nombredbquery[0])[2:len(nombredbquery[0])-4]
    host = str(hostquery[0])[2:len(hostquery[0])-4]
    password = str(passwordquery[0])[2:len(passwordquery[0])-4]
    username = str(usernamequery[0])[2:len(usernamequery[0])-4]
    connexion = 'mysql+pymysql://'+username+":"+password+"@"+host+"/"+nombredb+"'"
    def retorno():
        return str(connexion)    


from config import SQLALCHEMY_BINDS

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS['scada']= scadaConnect()
```

The error is as follows

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for information about how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`session` (first line in `scadaConnect()`) is only available in a request context a.k.a. view. It lives in the session cookie on the client and is sent to the server (and available to your view) only when the browser makes a request.

You will have to move the call to `scadaConnect()` to a view if you want to use `session`.